# Linear Equation in two variables problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations, word-problem

**$37$ Pens** and **$53$ pencils** together cost **Rs. $320$** while **$53$ Pens** and **$37$ Pencils** together cost **Rs. $400$**, Find the **cost of a Pen** and that of **a Pencil**.

So far I had done the following:
Let cost of 1 Pen be $\mathrm{Rs}.x$

And let cost of $1$ Pencil be $\mathrm{Rs.}y$

So, equations will be:

$37 \cdot x + 53\cdot y = 320 \mathrm{-----} (1)$

$53 \cdot x + 37 \cdot y = 400 \mathrm{-----} (2)$

Now which formula I should apply to solve this linear equation in two variables.

**Please Help**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x$ be the cost of a pen, and let $y$ be the cost of a pencil.

Then $37x+53y=320$ and $53x+37y=400$.  We have two linear equations in two unknowns. In principle this system of equations is routine to solve for $x$ and $y$, but it might be kind of messy.

But note the nice partial symmetry, and observe that
$$(37x+53y)+(53x+37y)=90x+90y=90(x+y).$$

**Remark:** So now we know that the combined cost of a pen and pencil is $8$. So we are finished. But what about the *individual* costs? Note that $(53x+37y)-(37x+53y)=16(x-y)=400-320$. So $x-y=5$. Now we can easily find $x$ and $y$. For $(x+y)+(x-y)=2x=13$ and therefore $x=6.5$. It follows that $y=1.5$.

Answer (score 1):

x - cost of a pen
y - cost of a pencil

37x + 53y = 320

53x + 37y = 400

you should be able to proceed. Try find value of x from one equality an set it up to second. then you have equality with y only, so can find an answer